# how to disable other input field if I get "matched" string value I'm passing in 1st input field Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I'm using template driven form and I need to disable other input field if other input field is matching with same string what I'm entering.
for example 1st input value if it is="sample" then other input should get disable.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="sample" 
  [(ngModel)]="sample" 
  #sample=ngModel 
  required="true" />

<input 
  type="text" 
  name="sample1" 
  [(ngModel)]="sample1" 
  #sample1=ngModel 
  required="true" 
  [disabled]="sample.value==sample" />
```

Please tell me how I can achieve this, I'm trying to use disable but I'm not understanding how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think placing template variables on these inputs(`#sample`, and `#sample1`) and assigning them `ngModel` is kind of redundant when you're already using `[(ngModel)]`. You'll get everything in your properties `sample` and `sample1`. So you can get rid of these template variables `#sample`, and `#sample1`.

But simply doing this won't work in a case when you fill a value of `sample` and then empty it. In that case, the second input will still get disabled.

It seems like a bug with Angular. Not sure about it. As a workaround, you can add another property in your Component Class that records the changed value of `sample` and `sample1` and then disable/enable the `sample1` text field. Here's how:

**Template:**

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="sample" 
  [(ngModel)]="sample"
  required="true"
  (change)="shouldBeDisabled()" />

<br><br>

<input 
  type="text" 
  name="sample1" 
  [(ngModel)]="sample1"
  required="true" 
  (change)="shouldBeDisabled()"
  [disabled]="shouldInputBeDisabled" />
```

**Component Class:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  sample;
  sample1;
  shouldInputBeDisabled;

  shouldBeDisabled() {
    this.shouldInputBeDisabled = this.sample !== '' && this.sample === this.sample1;
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qskhq1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Also, since the below input is required as well, you might not be able to submit the form if there's a validation on the submit button. Do the needful in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth...but I want to check 1st input value then need to disable.

Comment: Try the updated answer. It will first check if `sample` is defined.

Comment: No..It's not working, with your solution how its going to get the first input value and compare??

Comment: Thank yo so much @Siddharth for your time but your first answer was right, I'm sorry I was doing one silly mistake, please update it again with your 1st answer, I''ll make that as correct answer.

Comment: anything I'm entering inside 1st input field and removing so 2nd input field is getting disable.